# Notify change to object property in list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a list of objects named accounts that are bound to a vaadin data grid. I also have logic that updates a balance property on on each account with a large list of transactions.

```
_updateAccountBalance: function() {
    this.accounts.map(account => { account.balance = 0; });
    this.transactions.map(trans => { trans.account.balance += trans.amount; });

    // This doesn't notify other watchers of the accounts
    //this.set("accounts", this.accounts);

    // hack to get notifications to work
    this.accounts.map((account, idx) => {
        this.set("accounts." + idx + ".balance", account.balance);
    });
}
```

My question is: Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Because there are a lot of transactions, using set in the accumulator map would generate a lot of notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the array returned from the map function instead.

```
var accounts = [{balance: 23}, {balance: 3}, {balance: 2}]
var newAccounts = accounts.map(account => { 
    account.balance = 0;
    return account;
});

this.set("accounts", newAccounts);
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. It effectively clones the array. I tried looking into using the notifySplices Base call but it seemed pretty complicated.